# Is it possible to type an object with properties that are an intersection of multiple other object values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

This is a difficult to explain question. I'm trying to create a small library that can create components, and then later on when a user queries for entities that have those components, it returns a typed Entity with those components as the properties and value types. Something like this:

```js
type Component<T> = {
  name: string;
  type: T;
};

function createComponent<T>(name: string, type: T) {
  return {
    name,
    type
  }
}

interface Transform {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
const TransformComponent = createComponent<Transform>("transform", { x: 0, y: 0 });

interface Body {
  height: number;
  width: number;
}
const BodyComponent = createComponent<Body>("body", { height: 100, width: 100 });
```

These 'components' are eventually mapped onto entities, using name/type as property/value. I then provide a function for users to query for these entities, and be able to get strongly typed objects based on these components being available:

```js
// queryEntities ensures the entities array is only filled with entities that have those components as mapped properties
const entity = queryEntities(TransformComponent, BodyComponent);
console.log(entity.transform.x);
console.log(entity.body.width);
```

I've tried something with a UnionToIntersection utility and the new `infer` key to mmap the value of the name/type properties to no avail. Like this:

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> = U extends { name: infer Name; type: infer Type }[]
  ? { [key in Name extends string ? Name : never]: Type }[]
  : never;

function queryEntities<T extends Component<any>[]>(...components: T) {
  // logic here to filter out all entities with entity[component.name];
  return filteredEntities as UnionToIntersection<T>;
}
const entities = queryEntities(BodyComponent, TransformComponent);
for (const entity of entities) {
  console.log(entity.body.height);
  console.log(entity.transform.x);
}
```

As you can see, I get this type out of the other end (XBody/XTransform are just placeholder testing types that are similar to Body/Transform):

[image: Type error]

When in reality I want something like:

```
const entities: {
    transform: Transform;
    body: Body;
}[]
```

To sum up, I make multiple objects like `{ name: 'property1', type: { foo: 'bar'} }`, then I make a single object that maps all of those like `{ property1: { foo: 'bar' } }`, but I don't know how to make a type that can map the value of many objects as many properties of one object.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3xY2W) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Heck yea it works! Same as above, could you explain why this works? The `${number}` seems like magic, and I don't know why the `string` type has to be `K extends string` (amongst other things :P).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the compiler to know that the elements of the array that is returned from  `queryEntities(TransformComponent, BodyComponent)` have both a `transform` and a `body` property, then the `name` properties of `TransformComponent` and `BodyComponent` need to be more narrowly typed than just `string`.  They need to be the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"transform"` and `"body"` respectively.

And that means that before you even worry about `queryEntities`, you need to change `createComponent`'s call signature.  It cannot only be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` corresponding to `type`; it must also be generic in the type `K` responding to `name`:

```
function createComponent<K extends string, T>(name: K, type: T) {
    return { name, type }
}
```

which results in:

```
const TransformComponent = createComponent("transform", { x: 0, y: 0 });
/* const TransformComponent: {
  name: "transform";
  type: { x: number; y: number; };
} */
const BodyComponent = createComponent("body", { height: 100, width: 100 });
/* const BodyComponent: {
name: "body";
  type: { height: number; width: number; };
} */
```

If you want to give that output type the name `Component`, you can, but it would need to be generic in `K` for the same reason:

```
type Component<K extends string, T> = {
    name: K;
    type: T;
};

function createComponent<K extends string, T>(
    name: K, type: T
): Component<K, T> {
    return { name, type }
}

const TransformComponent = createComponent("transform", { x: 0, y: 0 });
// const TransformComponent: Component<"transform", { x: number; y: number; }>

const BodyComponent = createComponent("body", { height: 100, width: 100 });
// const BodyComponent: Component<"body", { height: number; width: number; }>
```

Anyway, now we can actually move on to the call signature for `queryEntities()`.

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
declare function queryEntities<
    T extends Component<any, any>[]
>(...entities: T): {
    [I in `${number}` & keyof T as T[I]['name']]:
    T[I]['type']
}[];
```

The idea is that `queryEntities` is generic in the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `T` corresponding to the `entities` rest parameter, which we [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be an array of `Component<any, any>` elements.

If you call `queryEntities(TransformComponent, BodyComponent)`, then `T` will be inferred as the tuple type `[Component<"transform", { x: number; y: number; }>, Component<"body", { height: number; width: number; }>]`. So the goal is to map that tuple into the desired output type `{transform: {x: number; y: number}; body: {height: number; width: number}}[]`.

The mapping from `T` to the element type of the output array is `` {[I in `${number}` & keyof T as T[I]['name']]: T[I]['type']} ``.  Let's break that down.  First, we are [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `` `${number}` & keyof T ``, which is just those keys of the tuple type `T` which are numeric strings.  The type `` `${number}` `` is a so-called *pattern* [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598).  Tuple types are arrays and have all the array keys like `"length"` and `"forEach"`, and we don't want to iterate over those.  They also have strongly typed keys corresponding to the positioned elements, and these are numeric strings like `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, etc.  For example:

```
type Tee = [typeof TransformComponent, typeof BodyComponent];
type KeyofTee = keyof Tee & {};
// type KeyofTee = number | typeof Symbol.iterator | typeof Symbol.unscopables 
// | "length" | "toString" | ...
type NumericStringKeyofTee = keyof Tee & `${number}`;
// type NumericStringKeyofTee = "0" | "1"
```

So we only want to iterate over those numeric-like keys. Anyway, for each numeric-like index `I` of the tuple type `T`, we want to [remap](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) the property key to the type of the `name` property of the element at that index.  That is, `T[I]["name"]`, where we use two [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html); the `T` type is the tuple of `Component`s, and `T[I]` is the type of the `I`th `Component` element of `T`, and `T[I]["name"]` is the type of the `name` property of that element.  As for the property *value*, we want to use the `type` property of the `I`'th component: `T[I]["type"]`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const entities = queryEntities(TransformComponent, BodyComponent);
/* const entities: {
  transform: { x: number; y: number; };
  body: { height: number; width: number; };
}[] */
for (const entity of entities) {
    console.log(entity.transform.x);
    console.log(entity.body.width);
}
```

Looks good.  Each element of the input gets transformed into a key-value pair of the array elements of the output, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPksUgC4CeMyAwgPZgy3ATCkA8A0khAB6ksATKEiikATgEtgAcwA0SACoA+JAF48REltCQAXEg4BuTVuIUq+hca0BfYyaQAzAK7B4pCUyTwxEEPzoGJhZ2Ll5+YCERcSk5RSUACgdtcAh9DnlzNMUHAEp9QMZmVk55ZQ1TEl9SZzFgPCQdCEzKZBsHdod4JlFFMRBgKEdaMTBC4NY1b19-CHHi0gSAInEBoZGwJflcJB59AAZ5cgOkG1zrEgB6ACpvHtI+teHR+ZD9Akqm-RX+wefNi5aLLvZIkPaNZxgABGEDEgNMxwh0Nh8OIdg6SGulwcl0ud0GDwUv3WL3oRTeSFeJR+Tw2Wwa4OAkJhcKQiKZyNZNiUXXuSAAQrQBOQqQ91D4-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-zvLsFacoYbJDSGpyevKwoDf6hZjSW4blsWXLwjYq7xg4zxIAkhUPMV5BILhnXQLkR6VIVckQBuGC0NICT7Ruqz4aMG48K1voXYZ123fdA4UBuU3kBui3Ku9aKEDYQA)

Comment: That was a great explanation! Given, I think I'll still need to digest it for a bit, but it seems my first mistake was not knowing the `K extends string` was needed to narrow the type, and as well, that the tuple type also needed to be indexed.

Very much appreciated!